# Jaeger traceId not showing in logs

Tags: java, log4j, jaeger

I am trying to add the `traceId` to the logs of a Java Spring project for easier debugging. Tracing is already present in the project using `opentracing`:

```java
@Bean
public Tracer tracer() {
    Tracer tracer = TracerResolver.resolveTracer();
    if (tracer != null) {
        GlobalTracer.registerIfAbsent(tracer);
    }

    return GlobalTracer.get();
}
```

The logging uses `slf4j` with `log4j` and the pattern:

```
"%d %-5p trace=%X{traceId} [%c{1}] - %m%n"
```

However, in the logs, there is no `traceId` present. How could this be added?

On another note, checking the full MDC (by using `%X`), I see a `_requestId` field. Is it different from `traceId`?